# crnk json implementation Java API Doc

Tags: json-api, crnk

We are using crnk JSON API implementation on the server side (Java). I see the crnk documentation here http://www.crnk.io/documentation/. But, I am not able to find the corresponding Java API Reference documentation. Not sure if there is on available ?

Comment: The JSON API Specification is available here: http://jsonapi.org/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no, so far it is not available. but could be added as PR. release automation is currently in progress and the asciidoc documentation already gets automatically published. Adding JavaDoc next to it would be a minor effort.